# Error when trying trigger change

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have 2 textboxs in form, it exactly the same because it's a directive, render by ng-repeat with isolated scope.

```
<form name="inputForm" class="input-icon right"
      ng-class="{'has-error': hasError()}">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="model"
           class="form-control input-medium" name="textbox" ng-required="isRequiredValidation()">
    <ul class="error-message" ng-show="hasError()">
        <li ng-repeat="error in showErrors">{{error.message}}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
<form name="inputForm" class="input-icon right"
      ng-class="{'has-error': hasError()}">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="model"
           class="form-control input-medium" name="textbox" ng-required="isRequiredValidation()">
    <ul class="error-message" ng-show="hasError()">
        <li ng-repeat="error in showErrors">{{error.message}}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

It has `ng-required` to validate. But i want to trigger this validate from outsite form, I have a button, when I click, I trigger change:

```
$('form input').each(function (i, element) {
    $(element).trigger('change');
});
```

But I get an error :

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at http://localhost:29549/Scripts/angular-1.2.16/angular.js:78:12
    at beginPhase (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/angular-1.2.16/angular.js:12720:15)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/angular-1.2.16/angular.js:12509:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.listener (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/angular-1.2.16/angular.js:16632:15)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:5109:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:4780:46)
    at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:5021:12)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:5705:17)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:671:23)
    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:29549/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:280:17)
```

The first textbox trigger change ok, but the second one get this error.
Please help me to fix this. 
My main purpose is trigger the validate of textbox from outside of form.

Comment: What are you doing in isRequiredValidation()?  The error you're getting is usually due to calling scope.$apply() unnecessarily or too early.

Comment: @comradburk: this function verify does this control have required validation? if it true, required attribute will be added to this textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like it has something to do with this open issue that angular has:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6364

To workaround it, you can either wrap you function in $timeout that doesn't invoke dirty check (last parameter false), or use safe apply:

```
function safeApply(scope, fn) {
    (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) ? fn() : scope.$apply(fn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the the jQuery `trigger()` is causing the `$apply()` to be called for each element in the loop.

Its multiple calls to `$apply` that is causing the error. FWIW, its rarely a good idea to mix jquery and angular, you can typically use jqLite if you need jQuery equivalent operations.

**Edit**

I dug out some angular code that does something similar. The `forEach` might be closer to what you are after. It triggers the 'required field' error message if the field is `pristine`. It does this without requiring any manual `apply()` calls.

```
$scope.submit = (form) ->
    if form.$valid
        $modalInstance.close($scope.data)
    else
        angular.forEach form, (field) ->
            field.$setViewValue(field.$viewValue) if field.$pristine
```

Comment: It still have error when I use angular jquery lite `angular.element('form input')`